# How to check if DSviewer form is empty?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi im very new to C# I am using third party library Dynamsoft.Forms.DSViewer.
I want to check if the form is empty or not How do I do that. I've tried googling it and tried to see if there is a method in the library but no success so far

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can check if the count of `CurrentSelectedImageIndicesInBuffer` is 0.

Details are here: https://www.dynamsoft.com/help/TWAIN/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner/api/P_Dynamsoft_Forms_DSViewer_CurrentSelectedImageIndicesInBuffer.htm

Comment: thanks alot. Although I reconfigured the flow to avoid the check 
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using our product.

Do you mean you want to check if there are images in the viewer? If so, you can check [HowManyImagesInBuffer](https://www.dynamsoft.com/help/TWAIN/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner/api/P_Dynamsoft_Core_Business_ImageBuffer_HowManyImagesInBuffer.htm) after [Bind](https://www.dynamsoft.com/help/TWAIN/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner/api/M_Dynamsoft_Forms_DSViewer_Bind.htm) DSViewer with ImageCore. For any further assistance, please feel free to contact support[at]dynamsoft.com